# Only allow a subset of users to access a google app project

Tags: python, google-app-engine

We are trying to develop a project in google app engine for a senior project, and its set up in such a way that only a subset of user at our college should be able to login to it.  Our college uses google domains for email, so that is currently out login requirement (a college email though google that is), but how can we limit it to not just people without that domain, but a subset or per-approved users with that domain?  Also if it matters, within the subset of users, there are four additional types of usesr, who will have access to different pages, functions and information.

Right now we are just using the google login APIs, and we are at a loss of how to micro-manage the user pool.  Would we have to create a data store entry for each user who should be authorized to access the service and run a check at each page to ensure they have the privileges to be there?  Or does google provide some type of service to make this easier that I've missed?  Thanks folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to write a user model rather than access it with the Google accounts API? That way you could define user groups and access without having to rely on Google.

The Google Accounts API in the example is really for low-level init debugging.

Comment: Yea, that was kinda what I was thinking, I was just making sure I wasn't skipping over something.